# Copy cell values to different Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, variables

Firstly, let me apologise if this question has already been answered somewhere else. I had a good look but couldn't find anything that would help me.

Secondly, I'm sure there is a far more simple way to do this but I'm very new the VBA and I'm just trying to teach myself as I go along.

Ok, so I have a sheet at the end of my workbook that compiles information from the previous sheet and I want to copy those values that are all in row 2 to another workbook that we have a network drive.

I've managed to get this to work on the same sheet but not to another workbook (without using a userform).

It comes back with the error 'Invalid Qualifier' for the line
*Cells(emptyRow, 1.Value - DateRaised.Value*

Here is my code below,

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim DateRaised As Long
Dim CustomerName As String
Dim SiteAddress As String
Dim CallReason As String
Dim CustomerOrderNo As Long
Dim InvoiceNo As Long
Dim CovernoteNo As Long
Dim Findings As String
Dim ProductType As String
Dim Supplier As String
Dim Attempts As Long
Dim Condition As String
Dim DateClosed As Long
Dim CreditGiven As String
Dim CreditValue As Long
Dim IssueDays As Long
Dim Comments As String

DateRaised = Cells(2, "A").Value
CustomerName = Cells(2, "B").Value
SiteAddress = Cells(2, "C").Value
CallReason = Cells(2, "D").Value
CustomerOrderNo = Cells(2, "F").Value
InvoiceNo = Cells(2, "G").Value
CovernoteNo = Cells(2, "H").Value
Findings = Cells(2, "I").Value
ProductType = Cells(2, "J").Value
Supplier = Cells(2, "K").Value
Attempts = Cells(2, "L").Value
Condition = Cells(2, "M").Value
DateClosed = Cells(2, "N").Value
CreditGiven = Cells(2, "O").Value
CreditValue = Cells(2, "P").Value
IssueDays = Cells(2, "Q").Value
Comments = Cells(2, "R").Value

Dim WrkBk As Workbook
Dim WrkSht As Worksheet

Set WrkBk = Workbooks.Open("R:\6024 Onsite\COVER NOTE WORKFLOW\Database\Covernote Databse.xlsx")
Set WrkSht = WrkBk.Sheets("Covernote Database")
WrkSht.Activate
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = DateRaised.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = CustomerName.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = SiteAddress.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = CallReason.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CustomerOrderNo.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = InvoiceNo.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = CovernoteNo.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = Findings.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = ProductType.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = Supplier.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = Attemps.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 12).Value = Condition.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 13).Value = DateClosed.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value = CreditGiven.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = CreditValue.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 16).Value = IssueDays.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 17).Value = Comments.Value

WrkBk.Close (SaveChanges = False)

End Sub
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be a very happy man.

Comment: `DateRaised` is not a cell... this way it would be `Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = DateRaised` without the `.Value`... same for the other lines

Comment: Also something like `Dim AllValues As Variant` with `AllValues = [A2:R2].Value2` is possible. Insert the values then with `Cells(emptyRow, 1).Resize(,17).Value = AllValues` ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel: but there's a "hole" in values: they range form column "A" to "D" and then from "F" to "R"

Comment: Oh yes... I missed that... sorry ;P (still, it could be done with 2 arrays then) :D

Comment: Haha, whoops. That's just me forgetting the alphabet again.

Comment: It should just be A through to Q

Answer (score 2):

it's because you're attempting to treat *value* types (like `String` and `Long`) variables as if they were `reference` type (objects) ones calling their `Value` property:

```
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = DateRaised.Value
```

while you can't (unless you use User Defined Types): *value* type variables can be only accessed as they are:

```
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = DateRaised
```

but you can simply code like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim curSht As Worksheet

    Set curSht = ActiveSheet
    With Workbooks.Open("R:\6024 Onsite\COVER NOTE WORKFLOW\Database\Covernote Databse.xlsx").Sheets("Covernote Database")
        emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) + 1
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Resize(, 17).value = curSht.Cells(2, 1).Resize(, 17).value '<-- paste values from originally opened sheet range A2:Q2
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: @Peter Peazy Littlefield: and one question: why copying all values in that opened workbook and then discard changes? Aren't you supposed to use `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = True` instead?

Comment: Yeah you're right. I tried your code but it doesn't leave anything in the target workbook regardless of if I put true or false.

Comment: Also, I removed the '.value' from the relevant line in my code and it works but it pastes into the source workbook instead of the target. Can you see why this would be happening?

Comment: see edited code where:1) handled contiguous range from A to Q 2) added `.Value` after `curSht.Cells(2, 1).Resize(, 17)`

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!